# How do I create unbreakable blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am creating a map on Minecraft, and I want the players to break certain blocks like trees, but I don't want them to break other blocks like stone bricks. Is there any command that can help me?

Answer (score 16):

You could put a player in Adventure mode using this command (in Java Edition 1.13+):

```
/gamemode adventure @p
```

Then, you would give them items with the `CanDestroy` or `CanPlaceOn` tags. Remember to use the exact capitalization as shown.

### `CanDestroy` NBT tag

This is an example of the `CanDestroy` NBT tag, which allows people in Adventure mode to destroy any of the blocks in that list, but not any other ones:

```
/give @p minecraft:wooden_pickaxe{CanDestroy:["minecraft:stone"]}
```

Here is what appears when hovering over the item that lets you know what the item can destroy:

[image: CanDestroy item tooltip]

### `CanPlaceOn` NBT tag

This is an example of the `CanPlaceOn` NBT tag, which allows you to place that block/item on any surface. For example, if the `CanPlaceOn` NBT tag included `minecraft:stone`, you could place the block (which is dirt in the example command) with that NBT tag on any of the blocks in the list above. Here is the example:

```
/give @p minecraft:dirt{CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:stone"]}
```

This is what would appear when hovering over the item to let you know what you can place the block/item on:

[image: CanPlaceOn tooltip]

### Tag Support

Both `CanDestroy` and `CanPlaceOn` support [tags](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tag). Tags represent a group of blocks/items and can be used in place of them. The following commands mean the same thing:

```
/give @p minecraft:stone_axe{CanDestroy:["#minecraft:planks"]}
/give @p minecraft:stone_axe{CanDestroy:["minecraft:oak_planks", "minecraft:spruce_planks", "minecraft:birch_planks", "minecraft:jungle_planks", "minecraft:acacia_planks", "minecraft:dark_oak_planks"]}
```

In earlier versions, specifying a block also included its other data values. For example, specifying Stone would also affect Diorite, Polished Diorite, Andesite, Polished Andesite, Granite, and Polished Granite. However, Java Edition 1.13 and higher require the use of tags instead.

### Your Request

What you have requested can be achieved using the following `/give` command:

```
/give @p minecraft:iron_axe{CanDestroy:["#minecraft:logs","#minecraft:leaves"]}
```

This will allow the player to destroy the current 6 types of [logs](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Log), [wood](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Wood), [stripped logs](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Log#Stripped_logs), [stripped wood](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Wood#Stripped_wood), and leaves.

Here is the tooltip of the iron axe:

[image: Requested item's tooltip]

It repeats the blocks twice because dark oak and acacia logs and leaves have a different block name than oak, spruce, birch, and jungle logs and leaves.

Comment: As of 1.13, the caveat about destroying any type of stone no longer holds

Comment: @pppery I've updated the answer to include that and instead recommend tags

Answer (score 3):

There is a crazy way of doing this:
Replace every block you want to be "invincible" by a barrier block, and summon invisible ArmorStand's at their position with the designated block on their head.

This works great, if you want to have only a few blocks, to be indestructable, but is completely overkill, if you want to create a whole wall.

But if you want, for example, 1 cobblestone block, to be unbreakable, but all other cobblestone blocks to be breakable, this is the best you can do (and the only thing, I think)

Comment: I don't think this could be a good idea, because if you have in mind all the blocks that the player cannot break, you'll have to put a lot of entities (ArnorStand) arround the map and this will make the game slower. But is a good idea for a single block.

Comment: Thats what I said: its a crazy idea, but it works perfectly, if you want to protect single blocks, instead of blocktypes

Comment: So, +1 for this.

Comment: It's not perfect as entities don't render at the edge of a screen sometimes.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Also, entities have a lower view radius than Blocks, so they will disappear at a certain distance, while other blocks stay visible

Answer (score 3):

Mining Fatigue or corrupt Haste can do this for you. In an area you want to protect, you can simply apply the effect there but remove it everywhere else. Here is the command to place in a repeating command block requiring no redstone to apply protection to the whole world:

```
/effect @a minecraft:haste 129 10000
```

Comment: Isn't this only viable if the "damage" done by the pickaxe to the block isn't modded?

Comment: @Oak What do you mean? Corrupted haste or Mining Fatigue makes it impossible to break at all.

Answer (score 2):

### Instant Replacement

Simply set up a repeating command block requiring no redstone that replaces the block every time it is destroyed.

This is an image of what the command block would look like:

[image: Correct settings and command]

This is the command you use:

```
/setblock <x> <y> <z> <block> replace
```

Make sure you replace the coordinates (`x`, `y`, and `z`) with the coordinates of the block, and `block` with the block ID (such as `minecraft:stone`).

When the block is broken, it will be instantly replaced with a block of the same type:

[image: Behavior if working]

Answer (score 0):

You could constantly place and destroy the block so they cant destroy it:

`/setblock ~ ~ ~ stone(or whatever block)`
`/setblock ~ ~ ~ air`

or use the fill command instead of the setblock

Answer (score 0):

How to make it so you can only break tree logs and leaves in adventure mode:
Copy one command at a time and run each command in your map.

1.13:

```
/give @p diamond_axe{CanDestroy:["minecraft:oak_log","minecraft:oak_leaves"]}
/give @p shears{CanDestroy:["minecraft:leaves"]}
```

1.12 and under:

```
/give @p diamond_axe 1 0 {CanDestroy:["minecraft:log","minecraft:leaves"]}
/give @p shears{CanDestroy:["minecraft:leaves"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Falling Block in Barrier

You can use the `summon` command to place a floating falling block inside a barrier. This has some drawbacks, mainly that falling blocks are entities and that they drop after a while.

[image: Floating falling block inside a barrier]