# How can I make some blocks unbreakable in Minecraft but some aren't?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-redstone

So I want to build a map where the blocks in spawn can't be broken but if you place a block you can break that block but you still can't break the default blocks kind of like BedWars on Hypixel. I thought this was a duplicate of the existing ones but it seems like those would make it so that you either cant break blocks you build or even build them in the first place.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create unbreakable blocks?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/250631/how-do-i-create-unbreakable-blocks)

Comment: @Wabbit. No that is slightly different than what I wanted