# Prevent people from mining specific blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a prison, and I want to prevent people from mining specific blocks.

How do I prevent players from destroying cracked stone bricks, signs, and red carpet blocks?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create unbreakable blocks?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/250631/how-do-i-create-unbreakable-blocks)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the "scoreboard" to replace broken blocks of x with a new one automatically, but that's a bit tricky. Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Well, I don't know how to do that *specifically*, but I do know that you can make it so that the trapped player is in adventure mode, but anyone not in the cell would be in survival mode.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, there is no way to "stop" players from mining a breakable block unless they are in adventure mode. I am not sure what you want. Are you making a prison escape game? Or that you simply need to trap people in a cell such that there is no escape at all? If it is the latter case, put a repeating command block under each cell (probably 1x1x2 blocks space) and set gamemode to adventure for all players standing above it. Also, remeber to deop them so that they won't use `/setblock` to destroy the command block or otherwise, with `/fill`.

Same thing goes for making a prison map. I assume that most prison maps allow you to break something in order to escape, which is still done with adventure mode, where you can set certain tools to destroy certain blocks with flags and tags.

In short, you can't prevent players from "breaking specific blocks" but instead allow adventure players to break certain blocks with tools. Still, if you insists on doing so I have a final trick up my sleeve --- repeatedly `/fill` the area with red carpets, stone bricks, and signs. So that as soon as players break these blocks they are immediately replenished. One downside to this is that players could farm carpets and signs, just saying in advance.